# Laravel & Vuejs. I can post but i can't get data

Tags: laravel, vue.js

i can post data using a Post function and it works perfectly. But i can't get data from my database. i don't know how to fix that. Someone can help please ?

Here is my get function in the view page.

```
var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    message: '',
    infos: [],
    info: {
        id: 0,
        cv_id: window.Laravel.idExperience,
        titre: '',
        body: '',
    },
},
methods: {
    getExperiences: function () {
        axios.get(window.Laravel.url + '/getexperiences/' + window.Laravel.idExperience)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(reponse.data);
                this.infos = response.data;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('errors: ', error);
            })
    },
```

My get function in the controller

```
  public function getExperiences($id){
$cv= Cv::find($id);
return $cv->infos;   
}
```

[In my Devtool there is no object in Infos. it's empty until i post data using my post funstion.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6Ibj.png)

Thank you in advance !!

Comment: Where are you calling `getExperiences()`? Also, what is actually outputted in the console?

Comment: My route : 
Route::get('/getexperiences/{id}', 'CvController@getExperiences');

The console output is empty !

Comment: Where in your JS code are you calling code `getExperiences()`?

Comment: In a list group item using : v-for="info in infos"  then @{{ info.titre }}
That what you mean ?

Comment: What is the devTools output? can you post a screenshot of it?

Comment: In the network tab search for the XHR type of request, select the getexperiences request, in the headers tab of the request, is the response 200 OK, also, what do you see on preview ?

Comment: In the network i can't see the getexperience function. but when i post something i have a 200 response for my addexperience. In the preview it's empty. And in my Devtool Vuejs, there no object reported. it's empty until i post something. Then i have data.

Comment: yeah, you open the devTools then you make the request you want to record... if theres no data showing, no data is being returned. Also, i think you wont see it as getexperiences you'll see the id you are posting...

Comment: We'll also need to see the CV and Info Models ... since we don't know how are you declaring the relationship... Laravel would not give you an error if you just return $cv->anyrelationthatdoesntexist

Comment: And what DigitalDrifter pointed, the json part, is highly recommended for working with vue.js

Comment: Ok, so you are at least calling `this.getExperiences()` somewhere in your code?